# JS | do-while - guess number | wrong output

Tags: javascript, alert, do-while, prompt

I have a problem with the do-while. When I type into an input form a different number than 15, it still says 'success', but it shouldn't, because the right number is 15. How could I change the do-while to recognize when I type other number than 15? Thanks for any suggestions.

```js
//works when type only 15
do {
    var guess = prompt("Guess a number between 1 and 20");
} while (guess !=15)

alert("Success!");

//this part works when I type 15 or different number
function guessWage() {
do {
    var guess = document.getElementById("guessNumber")
    if (guess.value != 15) {
        guess.value = false;
    }
} while (guess.value === 15)
    alert('you guessed the number');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Issue App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wageup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
       <h2>While loop</h2>
        
        <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">Array backwards:</span></h5>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="resultMonthly">
        </div>
        <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">Array forwards:</span></h5>
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="resultDaily">
        </div>
        
        <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">Guess, how much full-stack dev earns</span></h5>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type the number" aria-label="Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="guessNumber">
        </div>
               
        <button onclick="guessWage()" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Guess it!</button>
        
        
    </div>

        
        
                
        <!-- Scripts -->
                
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="whileloop.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Ok, I changed the string to Number with `Number(var)`, but now it's giving me an infinite loop. I'm little bit confused. Someone knows what to add into this do-while?

```js
function guessWage() {
do {
    var guess = document.getElementById("guessNumber")
    
} while (Number(guess.value) !== 15)
    alert('you guessed the number');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Issue App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="wageup.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="container">
       <h2>While loop</h2>
        
        <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">Array backwards:</span></h5>
        <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" id="resultMonthly">
        </div>
        <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">Array forwards:</span></h5>
        <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" id="resultDaily">
        </div>
        
        <h5><span class="badge badge-secondary">Guess, how much full-stack dev earns</span></h5>
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">$</span>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type the number" aria-label="Number" aria-describedby="basic-addon1" id="guessNumber">
        </div>
               
        <button onclick="guessWage()" type="button" class="btn btn-info">Guess it!</button>
        
        
    </div>

        
        
                
        <!-- Scripts -->
                
        <!-- Jquery -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <!-- JS -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="whileloop.js"></script>
        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `value` property of `<input>` elements will always be a string, and so no `input` will ever have a value that's `===` to the number 15.

Comment: The `prompt()` returns a string, not a number.

Comment: you have indefinite loop here if i guessed right about what you are trying to say for first..unless the prompt get value 15 it will never get out of first do while..also in second part you are comparing string with int val so either cast value of input to int or put "15" in quotes

Answer (score 0):

Javascript uses `==` `!=`, but you should always use `===` and `!==`.

Since the former can have unpredictable results sometimes. Moreover, you are comparing a string to an integer. Try converting them beforehand using `Number(var)`

Comment: The results are very predictable and often useful. Using `==` and `!=` allows evaluation of strings as ints or floats without conversion, as well as any datatype as boolean or as null.

Comment: *you should always use*... Theres a *because* missing.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you are trying to achieve is not clear.. if you simply want to compare the values on button click you dont need a loop in that case.so something like..

```
function guessWage() {
    var guess = document.getElementById("guessNumber")
    if (guess.value != "15") {
        // do what you want here if guess is wrong.
        alert('wrong guess');
    }
    else
    {
        // do what you want if guess is right
        alert('right guess');
    }    
}
```

OR

```
function guessWage()
{
    var guess = document.getElementById("guessNumber")
     if (Number(guess.value) != 15) {
        // do what you want here if guess is wrong.
        alert('wrong guess');
        }
    else
    {
       // do what you want if guess is right
       alert('right guess');
    }
}
```

feel free to comment about if anything is there i will update my answer.

Comment: You're right with your code and idea. But what if I want to type the input in a popup that will not be closed until I type a proper number? Then I need a while, right?

Comment: hey @Adam in that case also i guess wont need the loop ..as your function will only prompt right guess on correct input else it will fall for first condition resulting in kinda loop..